# Automation script to compare the data of an MS-excel file with a MS-Access file

Tags: java, excel, c#-4.0, selenium-webdriver, vba

I need to create an automation script. I will be given a MS Excel file and a MS-Access file. The script will read the data from both the excel and access files, compare them and the rows having different values will be printed out with the contents. How should i proceed? Which tool will be needed?

Answer (score 1):

You can read both files using OleDB.   I would parse out the data for each into a Dictionary, with the key being the column name, then iterate over one, checking the other.  You could even double-check it by swapping the iterations as well.

```
Dictionary<String, String> resultsExcel = read(); //whatever you use to read it, could be OleDB, but there are multiple ways of reading an excel file in C#.
Dictionary<String, String> resultsAccess = read(); //whatever you use to read it.  Probably will be OleDB for this one.

//Iterate over each, checking the other's data, and storing the rows that are different.
```

You may, even, be able to do the entire comparison with SQL if you use OleDB.  Not sure, but it might be possible.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but actually I have never worked with Dictionary. Do I need to read the Excel and Access file into datatables and then copy the contents of the Datatable into Dictionary? Can you be a bit more detailed?

Comment: I am able to add an Excel data to a dictionary, but how to add Access data to a dictionary?